# How to generate word document with data from database in asp.net 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i have a database application that stores data that we want to report in Microsoft Word.
i have database with 10 tables i want to generate a word document with data from database. when i click the button it ask file name,path and generate a new word document with data from database.

i am using asp.net 2010 web application and sql server 2008.

i want to make a record from the database data to word document. in this document related to health department...

i need link or code ..

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Check this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/01/19/pushing-data-from-a-database-into-a-word-document.aspx

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docName, true))
{
MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
Document doc = mainPart.Document;
//Create new table with predefined table style
Table table = new Table();
TableProperties tblPr = new TableProperties();
TableStyleId tblStyle = new TableStyleId();
tblStyle.Val = "PredefinedTableStyle";
tblPr.AppendChild(tblStyle);
table.AppendChild(tblPr);
string[] headerContent = new string[] { "Name", "Subcategory", "Price", "Image" };
//Create header row
TableRow header = CreateRow(headerContent, null);
table.AppendChild(header);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) is Microsoft's .Net library that lets you create and manipulate Office documents.

Here's the link to the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx).

I've used OpenXML to let a ASP.Net page dynamically generate Word documents from a database.  In the simple case I used Word to create a document template, then in C# I found the locations in the document that needed data from the database and replaced the content.

Comment: in this OpenXML SDK takes too much of time for installation now also it processing installing.